# Share TopicProcessor and Flux from ProjectReactor between two Spring boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

I have two spring boot applications that shared a common module. In that common module I create a TopicProcessor and a Flux from ProjectReactor

```
    @Bean
    public TopicProcessor<?> topicProcessor() {
        return TopicProcessor.<?>builder().autoCancel(false).share(true).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flux<?> eventFlux(TopicProcessor<?> topicProcessor) {
       return topicProcessor.publish().autoConnect();
    }
```

Then, I inject that TopicProcessor in the two Spring Boot instances (Spring Boot instance A, and Spring Boot instance B) and the Flux bean in only one of them (Spring Boot instance B).

So then, when I send an event from the instance B, I am able to receive it in the Flux. But, if I send an event from the instance A, I am not able to receive it in the instance B.

This is because the TopipcProcessor is a different bean in the instance A and B. Is it possible to share that bean between the two instances?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible, simply because sharing beans between two Spring Boot applications is not supported.